# does sbt have built-in buld steps comparable to Ant or a plugin project resembling such?

Tags: sbt

I admit I expected sbt to have general set of tasks built-in similar to [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tasksoverview.html)

Seemingly fundamental tasks like the ability to simply [copy](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html) a single arbitrary file don't seem to exist in sbt (or do they and I missed it)?

Is my best bet here to just use the [community ant plugin](https://github.com/sbt/ant4sbt)? That seems to somewhat miss the point of using sbt :)

Alternately is there a community effort or something to create many of these utility type tasks natively?

(I'm using sbt 0.13.)

Answer (score 4):

If you're coming from Ant, sbt might be a bit of a shock to you, but if you keep patience, I'm sure you'd really like it.

Unlike Ant where you achieve things by piecing together tasks, with sbt you create dependencies between settings and tasks, and tasks are just Scala code. So if you can do it in Scala, you should be able to do it in sbt too.

For basic tasks like copying a file, see [`sbt.IO`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt/latest/api/#sbt.IO%24) object and [`sbt.PathFinder`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt/latest/api/#sbt.PathFinder) class, which `File` can implicitly convert into. Here's an example that copies one file.

```scala
val someFileTask = taskKey[File]("describe it.")

someFileTask := {
  val src: File = baseDirectory.value / "data.txt"
  val out: File = baseDirectory.value / "data2.txt"
  IO.copyFile(src, out)
  out
}
```

Place the above in `build.sbt`, and you can execute it by running `someFileTask` in the shell.